# how to return a file that contains the output of the api in json format?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

i have an api that gives the output in json format as default.
i want the output to be saved in a file and return this file.

now my output is of the form:

```
[
  {"FName":"Folder1"},
  {"FName":"Folder2"},
  {"FName":"Folder3"}
]
```

i want this to be saved in a file locally and return this file when api is called.

Comment: What is your question? What is your problem? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `Content-Disposition` header to `attachment` and provide a filename:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    var value = new[]
    {
        new { FName = "Folder1" },
        new { FName = "Folder2" },
        new { FName = "Folder3" },
    };
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, value, this.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = "foo.json"
    };

    return response;
}
```

Comment: instead of allowing the client to download the file, can i save the file in the server and pass the path of it. so that i give only read only permissions to the client.